# Cannot make external request from website hosted in IIS

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core

I have an asp.net core website that does an external HTTP call from inside an action method

```
 public class MyController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult GetData()
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://test.api.somewebsite/data");
            webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            var resp = webRequest.GetResponse();
            var stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[10000];
            stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            return Ok(bytes);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            log(ex);
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Everything works fine (I get a 200 status from the external website) when I run it in IIS-Express or as a standalone console ASP.NET Core application.

When I host the website in my local IIS (same computer) I get this exception

**System.Net.WebException: An error occurred while sending the request. A connection with the server could not be established**

Anyone knows why I can not access that url from inside IIS?

Thanks

UPDATE
Actually I cannot make neither HTTP or HTTPS calls from inside IIS.

Comment: Have you tried calling localhost:port instead? The "A connection with the server could not be established" error is often because there is no server - like if you're connecting to the wrong address or port where no server exists

Comment: The problem happens only when my project is hosted in IIS. When I try from IIS Express then HttpWebRequest gets the response.   
Passing http://127.0.0.1 to HttpWebRequest it works in IIS as well.

Comment: Does it require a proxy to access the URL? On IIS Express, the code can use the proxy settings of your account, https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 while on IIS the code cannot get such.